# Jquery for Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using the below code for tooltip display for click event

Html Component:

```
 <a href="#" class="tooltip" data-description="Test tooltip">Test</a><br>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".tooltip", function() {
    $(this).tooltip(
        { 
            items: ".tooltip", 
            content: function(){
                return $(this).data('description');
            }, 
            close: function( event, ui ) {
                var me = this;
                ui.tooltip.hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1); 
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this).fadeOut("400", function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                );
                ui.tooltip.on("remove", function(){
                    $(me).tooltip("destroy");
                });
          }
        }
    ); // this is the line i'm getting "Expected Identifier, string or number". 
    $(this).tooltip("open");
});
```

I'm using jquery 1.9.1.js and jquery-ui.1.9.2.js. But I'm getting "Expected Identifier, string or number".

**EDIT:** Error resolved, but still I'm not getting tool tip on click event. 
Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You have an extra trailing comma after the `close` function of the tooltip settings object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yes Now error resolved, but tooltip is not displayed on click of href.

Answer (score 0):

This Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjVBOW seems to work for me with your code and latest jQuery and jQuery UI. Did it get resolved for you?

```
$(document).on("click", ".tooltip", function() {
  $(this).tooltip({
    items: ".tooltip",
    content: function() {
      return $(this).data('description');
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      var me = this;
      ui.tooltip.hover(
        function() {
          $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
        },
        function() {
          $(this).fadeOut("400", function() {
            $(this).remove();
          });
        }
      );
      ui.tooltip.on("remove", function() {
        $(me).tooltip("destroy");
      });
    }
  }); // this is the line i'm getting "Expected Identifier, string or number". 
  $(this).tooltip("open");
});
```